# Counting the number of "yes" occurrences in a column where the "yes" in a different sheet is calculated from a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003, countif

I have cell that shows the number of "Yes" present in a certain column:

```
=COUNTIF(Pipeline!AI$1500,"Yes")
```

The actual column that displays the "Yes" is derived by the formula as follows:

```
=IF(AH5="","",IF(AH5=0,"Yes",IF(AH5>0,"No")))
```

However the first formula always returns a 0, this may be a simple correction, but I would like to know how to obtain a count of "Yes" in that column which is derived by a function.

Comment: You need to change COUNTID function, instead of AI$1500 use AI:AI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the "Yes" is *derived by a function* or you type it yourself. It's the same value.

Your problem seems to be the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Pipeline!AI$1500,"Yes")
```

It's referencing only a cell (AI1500), not the whole column. To count the values in the column, change it to:

```
=COUNTIF(Pipeline!AI:AI,"Yes")
```

Comment: Furthermore, you could just skip pointing to AI and point directly to AH with `=COUNTIF(AH:AH, 0)` since the only time that `AI` will be "Yes" is when `AH` is 0